# Java spark dataframe join column containing array

Tags: java, arrays, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes df1 and df2. df1 has 1 column key of type String

```
df1.show()

key
----
k1
k2
k3

df2 has 2 columns
df2.show()
topic | keys
-------------
 t1  | [k1, k2]
 t2  | [pk1, pk2]
```

I want to join the 2 dataframes when df1.key is present in df2.keys. I saw previous examples posted here [Spark: Join dataframe column with an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41595099/spark-join-dataframe-column-with-an-array)

However, I am looking for a whole word match. Contains method is joining rows that have a partial match. What I mean is in the above example, I  don't want k2 to be joined with [pk1, pk2] because array does not contain key k2, it contains pk2.

Can someone suggest how to join in this case ?
Please provide example in JAVA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function "array_contains" can be used:

```
val df1 = List("k1", "k2", "k3").toDF("key")
val df2 = List(
  ("t1", Array("k1", "k2")),
  ("t2", Array("pk1", "pk2"))
).toDF("topic", "keys")
val result = df1.join(df2, expr("array_contains(keys,key)"))
result.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+--------+
|key|topic|keys    |
+---+-----+--------+
|k1 |t1   |[k1, k2]|
|k2 |t1   |[k1, k2]|
+---+-----+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is explode your array and get one line per key like that :

```
df2 = df2.withColumn("key", explode(df2.col("keys")))
df2.show()

+-----+----------+---+
|topic|      keys|key|
+-----+----------+---+
|   t1|  [k1, k2]| k1|
|   t1|  [k1, k2]| k2|
|   t2|[pk1, pk2]|pk1|
|   t2|[pk1, pk2]|pk2|
+-----+----------+---+
```

Then you can join on this new column :

```
Dataset<Row> result = df2.join(key, df2.col("key").equalTo(df1.col("key")), "inner")
result.show()

+-----+--------+---+---+
|topic|    keys|key|key|
+-----+--------+---+---+
|   t1|[k1, k2]| k1| k1|
|   t1|[k1, k2]| k2| k2|
+-----+--------+---+---+
```

Note that it is not very efficient because it duplicates the data.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about explode. But is there a better alternative ? Can joins take something like UDF(List<String>, String) and return a DataType.Boolean which can be used as a join condition ?